# How to get last modified time of a file in perl in the format returned from diff command?

Tags: perl, diff, stat, strftime

I want to display time in the same format as is displayed by the linux `diff` command.

```
D:\>diff -dub old.cfg new.cfg
--- old.cfg       2019-05-15 15:03:14.289950700 +0530
+++ new.cfg       2019-05-14 16:07:21.119695300 +0530
```

I want to show last modified time of a file as `2019-05-15 15:03:14.289950700 +0530`.
I used `stat` but I am not getting that nanosecond part. Alo, need timezone in given format. I tried `Time::HiRes` too, but couldn't get.

```
my $dt = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime((stat($old_file))[9]));
```

It returns: `2019-05-15 15:03:14`. Can you please help me to append the other info?

Comment: [BSD::stat](https://metacpan.org/pod/BSD::stat) looks promising for getting hires file times.

Comment: @Shawn: Is it possible with internal perl modules?

Comment: I don't think so. `stat` only returns seconds, and `POSIX::stat` is just it by another name.

Comment: Once you get the time in nanoseconds... divide by 1000000000 to get seconds, use that to get the time as a human-readable string like you're doing, and use the remainder to get the leftover nanoseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must first say, that's not going to be accurate.  Even as your hardware likely supports nanosecond resolution by the time it gets back to software it's hundreds of times off. (With a file's timestamp, presumably used only  as relative to other files, that may be less important.)

Having said that, the only way I find to claim nanoseconds is to use system's tools, so `stat`

```
my ($ts) = grep { /^\s*Access: [0-9]{4}/ } qx(stat $file);
$ts =~ s/^\s*Access:\s+//;
```

or, using `map` also as a filter

```
my ($ts) = map { /^\s*Access:\s+([0-9]{4}.*)/ ? $1 : () } qx(stat $file);
```

One problem here, of course, is that we have to parse output; so see your man pages and test your `stat`, and don't hope for much portability. Watch for system changes as output format of programs may change.  But I don't find nanoseconds claim in Perl.

For reference, on my CentOS 7 (under both `bash` and `tcsh`)

```
perl -we'$f=shift; print grep { /^\s*Access: [0-9]{4}/ } qx(stat $f)' file
```

prints, for a random file

```
Access: 2019-05-15 13:21:57.723987422 -0700
```

Once again, the "nano"seconds aren't accurate at all.

---

Another option, for perhaps more reliable output parsing, is to use `ls` with its `--full-time`

```
my $ts = join ' ', (split ' ', qx(ls --full-time $file))[5..7];
```

---

As always, when running external commands build your variables with care and quote and escape appropriately.  A good tool is [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote). Or, better avoid the shell altogether unless it's specifically needed. Best do all this using a module for running external tools.

Comment: Kudos for `ls --full-time`

Comment: [Time::HiRes's version of stat](https://perldoc.pl/Time::HiRes#stat) will return subseconds if available. If you do have to shell out, you should quote your filename with [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) or bypass shell parsing such as with [IPC::ReadpipeX](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::ReadpipeX).

Comment: @Grinnz Well, that doesn't help -- [`Time::HiRes::stat`] says "_In any case do not expect nanosecond resolution, or even a microsecond resolution._"  As for running external commands, yeah, sure, I hope they do it right. I'll add a comment

Comment: @KamalNayan Welcome.  I recall a version of man page for `ls` from years ago saying in bugs section "Too many options" or such :)  It's always worth checking whether there's something

Answer (score 2):

This is a multi-part challenge. The first challenge is to get a sub-second resolution on your file times, which is both OS and filesystem-dependent. The second part is to get the local timezone offset. All of this is doable on a modern system, however. You were on the right track with `Time::HiRes`, but `strftime()` is only going to get you part way. Here is an example program which takes files as arguments and prints the hi-res mtime per your requirements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw(stat);
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

sub timestr {
    my $t = localtime($_[0]);
    my $tstr = $t->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
    if ($_[0] =~ /(\.\d+$)/) { $tstr .= $1 }
    my $off = $t->tzoffset;
    return sprintf('%s %+02d%02d', $tstr, int($off->hours), $off->minutes % 60);
}

for (@ARGV) {
    my @stat = stat($_);
    print "$_\n  ".($! ? "Error: $!" : timestr($stat[9]))."\n";
}
exit(0);
```

Example output:

```
$ ./stat.pl stat.pl
stat.pl
  2019-05-16 20:02:38.76708 +1000
```

A lot of the heavy lifting is being done by `Time::Piece`, but there is a little bit of hackery going on to extract the fractional part of the time, and convert the timezone to the desired format (and I haven't tested it extensively). You may want to use `sprintf()` on the original incoming value to coerce a particular number of decimal places. My code just honestly reproduces the original fractional part.

Bear in mind that not all timestamps will have a fractional part, even on a filesystem which supports sub-second resolution. The file may have been copied from a source which does not have sub-second resolution, for example.

Comment: In retrospect, I think it's best to start the timestr() function by formatting the incoming number with sprintf(), then splitting it on the decimal place. This keeps all the time arithmetic nicely integer-based, and ensures you have a set number of decimal places.